# Display individual kmeans clusters from the clustering vector using wordcloud in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I've created a k-means cluster in R from a document-term matrix. The Clustering vector is as follows:

```
 doc1.txt doc10.txt doc11.txt doc12.txt doc13.txt doc14.txt doc15.txt 
        3         3         3         3         1         3         3 
doc16.txt doc17.txt doc18.txt doc19.txt  doc2.txt doc20.txt doc21.txt 
        3         3         3         2         3         3         3 
doc22.txt doc23.txt doc24.txt doc25.txt doc26.txt doc27.txt doc28.txt 
        3         3         3         3         3         3         3 
doc29.txt  doc3.txt doc30.txt  doc4.txt  doc5.txt  doc6.txt  doc7.txt 
        3         3         3         1         1         1         3 
 doc8.txt  doc9.txt 
        3         3
```

the document-term matrix is as follows:

```
     term1  term2  term3  term4  term4 
doc1   5      3     2      1      4
doc2   3      4     12     11     21
doc3   2      3     4      12     16
doc4   1      3     0      10     15
doc5   4      10    0      20     4
  .  
  .
  .
```

My question is how can I access the data of all documents in say cluster 3 and return a matrix of that! 
**I'm trying to plot the frequencies of terms min.freq = 3 from all documents in cluster 3 using a wordcloud.**

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cluster label vector is called `clusters`, you can use

```
docs3 <- gsub(".txt","",names(which(clusters==3)))
```

If your term document matrix is called DTM, you can get the submatrix for documents in cluster 3 by

```
DTM3 <- DTM[docs3,]
```

Comment: This worked for me.  What goes wrong?  Modify your question to include a reproducible example and I'll modify the answer to work for your particular problem.

Comment: sorry my mistake. This works forgot that my dtm also stores the ".txt"  I had to put that in the question as well. Thanks for your answer, accepted!